re-seed availability group database
I am trying to fix an issue with a 2 node AG that failed over causing all sorts of problems.  We were left with no choice but to remove the secondary database from the AG to get the DB working.  Now I need to reseed the secondary node and get the AG back up and running.
Currently the primary node DB is in not syncronizing, and the secondary is in restoring.  Secondary node db hasn't had logs sent to it in over a week, so I have taken a fresh full backup and have all log backups since then to restore to the secondary.
Questions:

I should be able to just overwrite the secondary DB with the fresh backups, then join it to the AG using the join only method right?

-OR-

Do I need to drop the secondary DB, or possibly remove the primary db from the AG before doing the restore?  I would like to not remove the primary from the AG since that will break the listener.

I'm trying to anticipate issues when I do this restore as this is a mission critical db.

Looked around some more and I was correct that dropping the secondary db or removing it from the primary node is not needed.  I can just overwrite the existing DB on the secondary with the most recent full and all tlog backups and manually join it to the AG.
